# How to apply the multiple composite functions to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

A minimum example is this:

```
ls = {1 + I, 2 - I};
Max@Re[ls]
Min@Im[ls]
#[ls] & /@ {Max@Re, Min@Im} (*want {2, -1}*)
```

The result is:

```
{{1, 2}, {1, -1}}
```

I don't know why is this..

Comment: `@` does not denote function composition. It denotes function applications. `f@g[x]` is *not* `(f@g)[x]` but `f@(g[x])`, merely a different notation for `f[g[x]]`.

Comment: You could just do `{Max@Re[#], Min@Im@#} &@ls` applying your function to `ls` instead of mapping it.

Comment: @Szabolcs But `Max[Re[ls]]` gives just a number, why need composite? Also `Max@Re[ls]` gives a number

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a minimal change in your code, you can replace `@` with [`Composition (@*)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

```
#[ls] & /@ {Max@*Re, Min@*Im}
```

> ```
>  {2, -1}
> ```

Consider also [`Through`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html):

```
Through @ {Max @* Re, Min @* Im} @ ls
```

> ```
> {2, -1}
> ```

***Aside:*** Why your code gives `{{1, 2}, {1, -1}}`:

```
Trace[#[ls] & /@ {Max@Re, Min@Im}] // Column
```

[image]

Notice that `Max@Re` is replaced with `Re` and `Min@Im` is replaced with `Im` in the very first step of evaluation.

Comment: If you can further add the reason why we need composite functions, the answer would be better. For example, why `Max@Re[ls] Min@Im[ls]` work as expected but not work when using `Apply`?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse, added a note re why you get `{{1, 2}, {1, -1}}` if you use `{Max@Re, Min@Im}` instead of `{Max@*Re, Min@*Im}` or `{Max@Re@#&, Min@Im@#&}`

Answer (score 3):

```
Map[{Max[Re[#]], Min[Im[#]]} &, ls, {0}]
```

Gives

```
{2, -1}
```

From help on Map

> Level 0 corresponds to the whole expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls = {1 + I, 2 - I};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0)

```
Comap[{Max @* Re, Min @* Im}] @ ls
```

{2, -1}

Answer (score 2):

```
ls = {1 + I, 2 - I};

Query[{Max @* Re, Min @* Im}] @ ls
```

{2, -1}

Answer (score 1):

```
ls = {1 + I, 2 - I};
```

---

Another way using `Thread`:

```
Last@Activate@#1@#2 & @@@ Thread[{{Max@Re, Min@Im}, Inactive[ls]}]
```

*Result*:

> {2, -1}